# Qt QML-CPP expose class as Q_PROPERTY

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to expose class as Q_PROPERTY?
(I know how to expose native variables.)

In my case, I want to handle chunk of data that change at the same time, and I want to render it at the same frame.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @JarMan is the usage in the link is OK? Is it a legitimate way to do that? It exactly what I need

Comment: @JarMan I tried to follow the link, but the implementation is not working.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: I implemented the example and got the error on the QML side "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes you can. As long as your custom class uses the Q_OBJECT or Q_GADGET macros, you can use Q_PROPERTY on this custom type.

For better understanding, have a look on this documentation: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_a_Custom_Class_in_C%2B%2B_Model_and_QML_View

Comment: Thank for the answer, it's good example, it's not what I need, I'll use it in other things.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are implementing wrappers for QDir and QFileInfo and that you have implemented both Dir and FileInfo as QObjects. Then to return the FileInfo in a method your code would look like this:

```cpp
FileInfo* Dir::fileInfo(const QString& fileName) const {
    FileInfo* fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(fileInfo, QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership);
    return fileInfo;
}
```

What the above code snippet is doing is creating a new FileInfo QObject but if the reference count of this QObject falls to 0 then we're allowing the QML/JS engine privilege to garbage collect it when it needs to be. The code snippet doesn't show the qmlRegisterType (or their QML_ELEMENT equivalent) that you would need to register both FileInfo and Dir classes properly, but, I am assuming that you already know how to do this. Because it is a QObject the app can take a copy of this object and can inspect (i.e. reflection) all of its properties and methods at runtime. Intellisense is possible.

The above pattern would be similar to a property as well. I would probably do something like:

```cpp
FileInfo* Dir::defaultFileInfo() {
    if (!m_FileInfo) {
        m_FileInfo = new FileInfo(this);
        QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(m_FileInfo, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
    }
    return m_FileInfo;
}
```

The above code snippet indicates that the parent class will control the creation and destruction of the request object and that there will be at most one instance created and subsequent access to the property will return the same instance.

As to Q_GADGET. Technically, I would only return a Q_GADGET where you know the entire lifecycle of the object, for instance, in a signal where you want to conveniently provide access to your class and methods. The advantage of this is there is no delegation to the QML/JS engine of your object, nor is there any type register or memory management. This is useful for exposing structures, but, the caveat, is that access to this class is limited to the duration of the signal handler and there is no access allowed beyond this. It is up to the app to copy out any values it needs from the class.

Comment: Great explanation, but is any example how I declare class by myself. Im sure there are some rules and guidelines that must follow.

Comment: I have some Networking classes here: https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-networking - I have other Qt projects on github too.